# Determining physical address for logical address

Tags: memory, cache, addressing

I have a simple segmentation system with the following segment table:

```
Starting Address    Length (bytes)
660                 248
1752                422
222                 198
996                 604
```

Determine the physical address for the following logical addresses; indiciate segment faults.
I know the answers, but I don't understand how they were calculated:

```
a. 0, 198  --  858
b. 2, 156  --  378
c. 1, 530  --  seg fault
d. 3, 444  --  1440
e. 0, 222  --  882
```

Comment: (1) This looks like a homework. Initial effort not demonstrated.   (2) This question doesn't deal with electronics design, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, Nick, the answers are known to the poster, it's the concept they are admirably trying to grasp - much better than the reverse case.  And this *is* typically a hardware design problem - an MMU is a part of the processor or board circuitry.  In this simple case it consists of a lookup table, a comparator and an adder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a) 660 + 198 = 858
b) 222 + 156 = 378
c) 530 > 422
d) 996 + 444 = 1440
e) 660 + 222 = 882
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to check if (offset < segment limit) for problem.
If it is, add offset + base address for the physical address.
If it is not, a segment fault will occur.

a) (0, 198) we will check  198< 248, which is true so we will calculate
Physical address = 660+ 198 = 858.

b) (2, 156) we will check  156< 198, which is true so we will calculate
Physical address = 222+ 156= 378.

c) (1, 530) we will check  530< 422, which is false so segment fault occur.

d) (3, 444) we will check  444< 604, which is true so we will calculate
Physical address = 996+ 444= 1440

e) (0, 222) we will check  222< 248, which is true so we will calculate
Physical address = 660+ 222= 882